RNP 1 vs RNAV(GNSS) STARs GPS Primary Requirement for A320?
1.Do we need GPS primary before enter the RNP 1 airspace and RNAV(GNSS) STARs and SIDs?
2.What will we do if we lose GPS primary function during RNP 1 airspace and RNAV(GNSS) STARs and SIDs?
Thank you


Yes. See FCOM for required equipment for RNP1. In case of RNAV1, at least in my manuals the GNSS is not required. Usually also the chart says explicitly that GPS/GNSS is required for the procedure.
Ask for radar vectors or alternative clearance

